# Is there any diferrence between includes(:associations).references(:associations) and eager_load(:associations) in Ruby on Rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

It seems `includes(:associations).references(:associations)` and `eager_load(:associations)` execute **exactly the same** SQL (LEFT OUTER JOIN) in Rails 5. So when do I need to use `includes(:associations).references(:associations)` syntax?

For example,

```
Parent.includes(:children1, :children2).references(:children1).where('(some conditions of children1)')
```

can be converted to

```
Parent.eager_load(:children1).preload(:children2).where('(some conditions of children1)')
```

I think the latter (query using `eager_load` and `preload`) is simpler and looks better.

**UPDATE**

I found a strange behavior in my environment (`rails 5.2.4.3`).

Even when I `includes` several associations and `references` only one of them, **all** the associations I included are `LEFT OUTER JOIN`ed.

For example,

```
Parent.includes(:c1, :c2, :c3).references(:c1).to_sql
```

executes a SQL which `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s all of c1, c2, c3.
I thought it joins only c1.

Comment: The main difference is that `.includes` tries to be smart using a complex set of heuristics to determine if its going to load the the records in one query or two queries. Using `.references` is one of the conditions that will cause it to delegate to `.eager_load` anyways which is why its joining `:c1, :c2, :c3`. If you know upfront that you are going to be using the association `.eager_load` does the job in a straight forward manner.

Comment: So when do I need to use `includes(:associations).references(:associations)` syntax? Well probably never as it will use `.eager_load` anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, `includes` + `references` ends up being the same as `eager_load`. Like many things in Rails, you have a few ways of accomplishing the same result, and here you are witnessing that first hand. If I were writing them in a single statement, I would always prefer `eager_load` because it is more explicit and it is a single function call.

I would also prefer `eager_load` because I consider `references` a kind of hack. It says to the SQL generator "Hey, I am referring to this object in a way that you would not otherwise detect, so include it in the JOIN statement" and is generally used when you use a String to pass a SQL fragment as part of the query.

The only time I would use the `includes(:associations).references(:associations)` syntax is when it was an artifact needed to make the query work and not a statement of intent. The [Rails Guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-eager-loaded-associations) gives this good example:

```rb
Article.includes(:comments).where("comments.visible = true").references(:comments)
```

As for why referencing 1 association causes 3 to be JOIN'ed, I do not know for sure. The code for `includes` uses heuristics to decide when it is faster to use a JOIN and when it is faster to use 2 separate queries, the first to retrieve the parent and the second to retrieve the associated objects. I was surprised to find how [often it is faster to use 2 separate queries](https://engineering.gusto.com/a-visual-guide-to-using-includes-in-rails/). It may be that since the query has to use 1 join anyway, the algorithm figures it will be faster to use 1 big join rather than 3 queries, or it may in general think 1 join is faster than 4 queries.

I would not in general use `preload` unless I had a strong reason to believe that it was faster than `join`. I would just use `includes` alone and let the algorithm decide.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know that I don't need `references` when I use Hash to pass conditions to includes query. (Rails Guide: "Using where like this will only work when you pass it a Hash.")